# When is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}x^{2i-1}}{1-x^{2i-1}}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{i}}{1+x^{2i}}$ useful?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, binomial-theorem

I recently came across this rather curious identity for $|x| < 1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}x^{2i-1}}{1-x^{2i-1}}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{i}}{1+x^{2i}}$$
The proof is fairly straightforward, so I won't go into details about it. I was wondering if anyone could give some examples of exercises where this identity is used (e.g. any other series that can be evaluated or simplified using this identity), as I feel it would be interesting to explore some questions relating to this.

Comment: Where did you find this identity?

Comment: It was in a mathematics magazine, but I have seen this before. The proof is fairly easy if you write out the terms on each side with the binomial theorem and reorder them to see that they are the same. I was quite intrigued by this result so I was wondering if it had any uses in finding more complicated sums